# ApiPlatform/Symfony - Implementing Optimistic Locking on the CRUD API

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com, optimistic-locking

Symfony, rather Doctrine, offers **Optimistic Locking** by adding the @Version Annotation to the property of an entity.
In practice the version-property on the User-Entity will then look like this:

```php
    /**
     * @Groups({
     *     "user:item:get"
     * })
     * @ORM\Version
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $version;
```

The **user:item:get** Group in the @Groups-Annotation will add the value of the version-property to the response of a GET-Request.
There is no direct implementation of any Request, we use the CRUD-API of an Entity that leverages internal Provider/Persister system.

Let us assume the current version on the User-Resource we are about to change is 10.

Executing a PUT-Request on that Resource with a body like this:

```json
{
  "zip": 10000
  "version": 5
}
```

will be completely valid. The zip-property will be changed to 10000, even though the version-numbers are mismatched.

What am I doing wrong? Is the internal Persister-system unable to validate the version number by itself or am I providing it incorrectly - is it not supposed to be in the request body?

Thanks!

Comment: you should use the expected version first (before updating User). Please take a look here: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#optimistic-locking

Comment: @rogeriolino what do you mean by "Use the expected version first"? Shouldnt the PUT with a mismatched version be rejected either way, regardless of a previous PUT that used the matching version?

Comment: What sort of code is implementing your PUT request?  Been awhile since I used it but what you have seems like it would work.

Comment: @Cerad it is the built-in CRUD API of an Entity. There is no direct implementation of the PUT-Request, it is all handled through internal persister systems.

Comment: @Bricklet I mean using the given `version` as the `expectedVersion`: ```$em->lock($entity, LockMode::OPTIMISTIC, $expectedVersion);```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I upgraded api-platform to version 3.0.0 and now it works as expected...

If you are using PHP-Attributes as Annotations, the version field should look like this:

```php
    #[
        Groups(["user:item:get","user:item:put"]),
        Version,
        Column(type: Types::INTEGER)
    ]
    private int $version;
```

Where **user:item:get** exposes that property on a GET-Request and **user:item:put** exposes it on a PUT-Request. That way the interal persister-system can validate the version passed in the request-body. So I probably did not have to upgrade, rather I could have just addded the **user:item:put** Group to the @Groups Annotation.

Another issue still persists, but that is currently a known problem. Sending the PUT-Request without a version-property in the body does not throw an OptimisticLockException, the request will pass through without error.